# How much server hardware is currently being used for virtualization?

Tags: virtualization

I'm trying to find out which percentage of real-world server hardware is being used for virtualization, and which one to directly run operating systems and applications.

I'm not asking for *your* personal experience here, but rather for some statistics, if such studies have been made by anyone (server vendors? VMware?). Also, historical data would be very useful.

Please provide sources and/or links, if at all possible.

Comment: So if we can't use personal experience then why don't you just google it like everybody else would do.  Anything I'd say would be my personal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gartner did some research a few years back, [here](http://eginnovations.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/virtualization-market-statistics-and-predictions-by-gartner/) is the summary.